# trying to create multiple visualgroups in silverlight, getting 'catastrophic failure'

Tags: silverlight, xaml, state

I have a button control I'm trying to create which can be in several different visual states, each visual state has a different colour applied to it when in a 'prsesed' state, here is what I have:

```
 <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="StateBlue">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Blue"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>

 <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="StateGreen">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Green"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
</vsm:VisualStateGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the VisualStates can't have the same name even if they are in different groups. Also, you better avoid animating the same property (Background) in more than one visual state groups.

Comment: oh right, but then how can I control the colours for when the buttons are selected and such? Like if I set 'stategreen' how can I make sure if someone presses down on the button the 'selected' visualstate for StateGreen is selected?

Comment: Hi, you should do this in the buttons default Pressed state. You can create two button styles. In ones pressed state, set the background of the button to blue; in the other, set to Green.